# How to make navbar stay fixed when scrolling

Tags: html, css, navbar

My problem is when I try to make navbar fixed ,it just disappear from my page .First thing that I've tried is to create a class called sticky that has position:fixed but when I call it my navbar stop showing ( I think it shrinks so much that text can be visible). Any ideas how to make the navbar static when user scrolls down ?

HTML CODE

```
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    
    <div class ="main">
        <div class="navbar ">
        
          <div class="container flex lead ">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">Proiecte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html">Recenzii</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <h1>CarolHousing</h1>
                  
            </div>
            <div class="social sm">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Showcase -->
    <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container grid">
            <div class="showcase-text">
                <h1>Easier Deployment</h1>
                <p>Deploy web apps of all kinds, from large scale enterprise APIs to static websites for individuals. Fill out the form to try a demo of our platform</p>
                <a href="features.html" class="btn btn-outline">Read More</a>
            </div>

            <div class="showcase-form card">
                <h2>Request a Demo</h2>
                 
                 <form>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

  
    <!-- Cli -->
    <section class="cli">
        <div class="container grid">
            <img src="images/cli.png" alt="">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Easy to use, cross platform CLI</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Deploy in seconds</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    

    

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer bg-dark py-5">
        <div class="container grid grid-3">
            <div>
                <h1>Loruki
                </h1>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2020</p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html">Docs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  
  min-height: 80px; 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}


.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.navbar .social a{

  margin: 0 2px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.navbar .social > *:nth-child(3){
  font-size: 28px;
  
}.showcase {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.showcase p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.showcase .grid {
  overflow: visible;
  grid-template-columns: 55% auto;
  gap: 30px;
}

.showcase-text {
  animation: slideInFromLeft 1s ease-in;
}

.showcase-form {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  animation: slideInFromRight 1s ease-in;
}

.showcase-form .form-control {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.showcase-form input[type='text'],
.showcase-form input[type='email'] {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b4becb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.showcase-form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.showcase::before,
.showcase::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -70px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');

:root {
  --primary-color: #047aed;
  --secondary-color: #1c3fa8;
  --dark-color: #002240;
  --light-color: #f4f4f4;
  --success-color: #5cb85c;
  --error-color: #d9534f;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

code,
pre {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}


/* Features */
.features-head img,
.docs-head img {
  width: 200px;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

.features-sub-head img {
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

.features-main .card > i {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.features-main .grid {
  padding: 30px;
}

.features-main .grid > *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

/* Docs */
.docs-main h3 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.docs-main .grid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.docs-main nav li {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.docs-main a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Tablets and under */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid,
  .showcase .grid,
  .stats .grid,
  .cli .grid,
  .cloud .grid,
  .features-main .grid,
  .docs-main .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .showcase {
    height: auto;
  }

  .showcase-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    animation: slideInFromTop 1s ease-in;
  }

  .showcase-form {
    justify-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    animation: slideInFromBottom 1s ease-in;
  }

  .cli .grid > *:first-child {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  .features-head,
  .features-sub-head,
  .docs-head {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .features-head img,
  .features-sub-head img,
  .docs-head img {
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .features-main .grid > *:first-child,
  .features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}

/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 110px;
  }

  .navbar .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  .showcase-form {
    width: 300px;
  }
}.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  align-self: start;
  
}
.main {
  min-height: 100vh; /*add*/
  height: 3000px; /*this is a test rule*/
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-outline {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px #fff solid;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

/* Backgrounds & colored buttons */
.bg-primary,
.btn-primary {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-secondary,
.btn-secondary {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-dark,
.btn-dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-light,
.btn-light {
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  color: #333;
}

.bg-primary a,
.btn-primary a,
.bg-secondary a,
.btn-secondary a,
.bg-dark a,
.btn-dark a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Text colors */
.text-primary {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.text-secondary {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.text-dark {
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

.text-light {
  color: var(--light-color);
}

/* Text sizes */
.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sm {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.md {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.lg {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.xl {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Alert */
.alert {
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.alert i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.alert-success {
  background-color: var(--success-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.alert-error {
  background-color: var(--error-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.sticky{
  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

.cli .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.cli .grid > *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me when I added `position:fixed`. Please upload the code that you tried and failed, WITH the `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is as advice.
Make it a rule to wrap all your content in the **main** div, like here:

```
<div class="main">
...
</div>
```

In my example, I used `position: sticky`.

In the css, I marked the edits.

```js
anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    opacity: [0.5,1],
    scaleX: [0, 1],
    easing: "easeInOutExpo",
    duration: 700
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .line',
    duration: 600,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    translateY: (el, i) => (-0.625 + 0.625*2*i) + "em"
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .ampersand',
    opacity: [0,1],
    scaleY: [0.5, 1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=600'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-left',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=300'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5 .letters-right',
    opacity: [0,1],
    translateX: ["-0.5em", 0],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=600'
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml5',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box; /*add*/
  margin: 0; /*add*/
  padding: 0; /*add*/
}

.navbar {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  
  min-height: 80px; 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
  
  z-index: 9999;
}
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}


.navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
}

.navbar .flex {
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.navbar .social a{

  margin: 0 2px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.navbar .social > *:nth-child(3){
  font-size: 28px;
  
}.showcase {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.showcase p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.showcase .grid {
  overflow: visible;
  grid-template-columns: 55% auto;
  gap: 30px;
}

.showcase-text {
  animation: slideInFromLeft 1s ease-in;
}

.showcase-form {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  animation: slideInFromRight 1s ease-in;
}

.showcase-form .form-control {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.showcase-form input[type='text'],
.showcase-form input[type='email'] {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b4becb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.showcase-form input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.showcase::before,
.showcase::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -70px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-3deg);
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');

:root {
  --primary-color: #047aed;
  --secondary-color: #1c3fa8;
  --dark-color: #002240;
  --light-color: #f4f4f4;
  --success-color: #5cb85c;
  --error-color: #d9534f;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

code,
pre {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}


/* Features */
.features-head img,
.docs-head img {
  width: 200px;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

.features-sub-head img {
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}

.features-main .card > i {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.features-main .grid {
  padding: 30px;
}

.features-main .grid > *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

/* Docs */
.docs-main h3 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.docs-main .grid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.docs-main nav li {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
}

.docs-main a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Tablets and under */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid,
  .showcase .grid,
  .stats .grid,
  .cli .grid,
  .cloud .grid,
  .features-main .grid,
  .docs-main .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }

  .showcase {
    height: auto;
  }

  .showcase-text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    animation: slideInFromTop 1s ease-in;
  }

  .showcase-form {
    justify-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    animation: slideInFromBottom 1s ease-in;
  }

  .cli .grid > *:first-child {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  .features-head,
  .features-sub-head,
  .docs-head {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .features-head img,
  .features-sub-head img,
  .docs-head img {
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .features-main .grid > *:first-child,
  .features-main .grid > *:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}

/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 110px;
  }

  .navbar .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  .showcase-form {
    width: 300px;
  }
}.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 40px;
  align-self: start;
  
}
.main {
  min-height: 100vh; /*add*/
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn-outline {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px #fff solid;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

/* Backgrounds & colored buttons */
.bg-primary,
.btn-primary {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-secondary,
.btn-secondary {
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-dark,
.btn-dark {
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-light,
.btn-light {
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  color: #333;
}

.bg-primary a,
.btn-primary a,
.bg-secondary a,
.btn-secondary a,
.bg-dark a,
.btn-dark a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Text colors */
.text-primary {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.text-secondary {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.text-dark {
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

.text-light {
  color: var(--light-color);
}

/* Text sizes */
.lead {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sm {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.md {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.lg {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.xl {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Alert */
.alert {
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.alert i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.alert-success {
  background-color: var(--success-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.alert-error {
  background-color: var(--error-color);
  color: #fff;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.sticky{
  
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

.cli .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.cli .grid > *:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}


/*Animation h1*/

/*.ml5 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  color: #402d2d;
}*/

.ml5 .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-right: 0.05em;
  padding-bottom: 0.15em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.ml5 .line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  transform-origin: 0.5 0;
}

.ml5 .ampersand {
  font-family: Baskerville, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: -0.1em;
  margin-left: -0.1em;
}

.ml5 .letters {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="navbar ">   
        <div class="container flex lead ">
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
                  <li><a href="features.html">Proiecte</a></li>
                  <li><a href="docs.html">Recenzii</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          <div>
          
        <h1 class="ml5">
          <span class="text-wrapper">
            <span class="line line1"></span>
            <span class="letters letters-left">Carol</span>
            <span class="letters ampersand">&amp;</span>
            <span class="letters letters-right">Housing</span>
            <span class="line line2"></span>
          </span>
        </h1>  
          
          
          
          </div>
          <div class="social sm">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <section class="showcase">
        <div class="container grid">
            <div class="showcase-text">
                <h1>Easier Deployment</h1>
                <p>Deploy web apps of all kinds, from large scale enterprise APIs to static websites for individuals. Fill out the form to try a demo of our platform</p>
                <a href="features.html" class="btn btn-outline">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="showcase-form card">
                <h2>Request a Demo</h2>
                 
                 <form>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="cli">
        <div class="container grid">
            <img src="images/cli.png" alt="">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Easy to use, cross platform CLI</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Deploy in seconds</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer bg-dark py-5">
        <div class="container grid grid-3">
            <div>
                <h1>Loruki
                </h1>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2020</p>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html">Docs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226774/discussion-on-answer-by-s-kuznetsov-how-to-make-navbar-stay-fixed-when-scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

set the the height of container ( must be navbar parent though ) to `100vh` and keep `overflow: auto` or set to `overflow-y: scroll`.

then set the position property on the navbar to 'sticky':

`position: sticky`

and enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to the navigation container.

```
position: fixed;
```

Here is a code example.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Works</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
}
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```